# Check two IEnumerable if their Count is equal

Tags: c#, ienumerable

How to check two IEnumerables whether they have same count without running through them individually. Means I do not want to do this Count() == Count().

I would like to find a way to do that in one pass. Any ideas?

Comment: Use IList or ICollection I think.

Comment: You can't. Enumerables might not even have a finite count.

Comment: You can't do it unless you cast them to a type that has a Count property which allows you to get count without iterating all items.

Comment: IEnumerable might not have a fixed count at any given time, depending on how it is being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. Whatever approach you choose, you will have to run through both sequences.

The most straightforward way is to use the `Count()` method, where would be an `O(1)` if both sequences are `List`. In this case, the `Count()` fails to get the value of list's property called `Count`.

Comment: Using `Count()` will take time proportional to the longer collection; better is to check whether either or both collections implement either `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>`.  If both do, compare their counts.  If one does, read its count and try enumerating that N+1 items of the other.  If the second collection ended after N, they match; if it ends sooner or doesn't end after N, they don't.  If neither implements a counting interface, iterate them both *simultaneously*, and stop as soon as one reaches the end.